# How to set background image only for a part of the textView

Tags: java, android, textview

I have a multiline textview and i want to set a background image only at the last three characters of the textview -> from tv.length() - 3 to tv.lenght()

Comment: probably use `2 textViews`

Comment: an image? not just a background color?

Comment: yes background image for only last three characters not for whole of the text

Answer (score 0):

This can help you a lot:

```
    String input = "stackoverflow.com";
    String firstCharactersResult = "";
    String lastThreeCharactersResult = "";

    if (input.length() > 3) {
        firstCharactersResult = input.substring(0, input.length() - 3);
        lastThreeCharactersResult = input.substring(input.length() - 3);

        textView.setText(HtmlCompat.fromHtml(firstCharactersResult + "<font color=\"red\">" + lastThreeCharactersResult + "</font>", 0));
    }
```

If you want to change the **background**, This is simple use 2 TextViews!
Set the firstCharactersResult to first TextView and set the lastThreeCharactersResult to second TextView.

Comment: Thanks bro, but i want to set an image as background not color

Comment: This is simple use two textviews and set the firstCharactersResult to first TextView and set the lastThreeCharactersResult  to second TextView

Answer (score 0):

You should use buildSpannedString :

```
buildSpannedString {
            append("str1")
            append(' ')
            color(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.red)) {
                append("red text")
            }
```

Comment: Thanks bro, but i want to set an image as background not color

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work:

```
Spannable spannable = new SpannableString(text);

spannable.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.WHITE), text.length(), text.length()-3, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

myTextView.setText(spannable, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```